# Is there a "selective" input command in LaTeX?

Tags: input, source

I'm likely going to have to write a document that includes some portions of source code, which I'd rather keep in separate source files. I know that I can include the contents of those files in my document using `\input{example.cpp}`, and use various environments to pretty-print the code, but the source files will certainly start with a few commented lines explaining what the code does, whether it can be redistributed and so on, and this will be irrelevant in the main document.

Is there a package or a specific command that allows me to omit those lines when including an external file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `listings` package with the `firstline` option:

```
\lstinputlisting[firstline=2]{file}
```

Comment: @Anthony: There is also a `lastline` option if you need it.

Comment: Yes, I've read the documentation, this will come in handy too.